# Determine if the sequence $\frac{3^n}{n^3+1}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here is how I approached this problem. I found that the sequence diverges by using some basic substitution patterns. Does this look about right? Or did I miss some other way to approach this?

[image: Here is how I approached this problem]

Comment: Yes, it's alright

Comment: The logic is right.  You may want to work on the presentation some.  Note how when you write limit it's inconsistent - you write both $lim$ and $limit$.  The preferable thing to do is to write `\lim`, which is formatted as $\lim$.  So, if you want to look at $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, you write this as `\lim_{n\to\infty}`.  This has the benefit that if you enclose it in `$$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$`, it will typset the $n\to\infty$ part below (like $$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$. Additionally, it can be good to try to name the theorem you're using (if possible).

That being said, all of your logic is good.

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything but I don't see that setting $a_n = 1/s_n$ was nescessary. $\lim s_{n+1}/s_n = 3 > 1$ so $s_n$ diverges.  It's the same thing but more direct.

Answer (score 1):

The root test
also works nicely here.

$\left(\frac{3^n}{n^3+1}\right)^{1/n}
=\frac{3}{(n^3+1)^{1/n}}
$.

Combine this with
$n^{1/n} \to 1$
and
$a^{1/n} \to 1$
as $n \to \infty$
for any $a > 0$
gives the result.

Note that,
by Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+n^{1/k-1})^n
\ge 1+n\cdot n^{1/k-1}
= 1+n^{1/k}
> n^{1/k}
$.
Raising this to the $n/k$ power,
$(1+n^{1/k-1})^k
> n^{1/n}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
n^{1/n}
&< (1+n^{1/k-1})^k\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}(n^{1/k-1})^j\\
&=1+\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}(n^{1/k-1})^j\\
&<1+\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}(n^{1/k-1})\\
&=1+n^{1/k-1}(2^k-1)\\
&=1+\dfrac{2^k-1}{n^{1-1/k}}\\
\end{array}
$

In other words,
$n^{1/n}
=1+O(\dfrac1{n^{1-1/k}})
$
for every $k \ge 2$.

Since the true bound is
$n^{1/n}
=e^{\ln n/n}
=1+O(\dfrac{\ln n}{n})
$,
this elementary bound
is quite good.